# linked list basic architecture in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I am new to C and I want to implement the linked list. This is my initial copied code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;               // integer data
    struct Node* next;      // pointer to the next node
} Node;

int main() {
    Node* A = NULL;
    Node* temp = malloc(sizeof * temp);
    temp->data = 2;
    temp->next = NULL;
    A = temp;
    printf("%d", A);
    return 0;
}
```

I have understood how pointers work, for example:

```
    //Example 2
    int a = 2;
    int* p = &a;
```

such that `p` holds the address of `a` and `*p` holds the content of it.

In the node example, the basic idea is to create an initial node, and then from there, to link other nodes when inserting at the end for instance. So, when we did this:

```
    Node* A = NULL;
    Node* temp = malloc(sizeof * temp);
```

we create a node `A`, my first question here, why I can't use the same concept of accessing its address and content `NULL` the same as in `Example 2` or how can I do that?

Second, when we created node `temp` and assigned `2` to its data, and `NULL` to its next, it's all clear, but when we did `A = temp`, this is not clear, what did we assigned exactly? I mean, how can I get from `A` to the next node, `A` now has `A->data = 2` and `A->next = NULL`, I was expecting `A->next` to store the address of `temp`, no? Please if you can explain in the simplest terms the basic abstract inner workings?

**Update**

For example, if I want to create a linked list with two elements `2` and `3`. Is the following code correct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;               // integer data
    struct Node* next;      // pointer to the next node
} Node;

int main() {
    Node* A = NULL;
    Node* temp = malloc(sizeof * temp);
    temp->data = 2;
    temp->next = NULL;
    A->next = temp;
    Node* temp1 = malloc(sizeof * temp1);
    temp1->data = 3;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    temp->next = temp1;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only created one node, `temp`, not 2 nodes.  because you made `A` a pointer to a struct, not a struct.    Also, be careful about assigning local (stack) variables to pointers. (`int* p = &a;`)  If you do that in a function instead of in main, the memory allocation disappears when you return from the function and the pointer to it becomes invalid.

Comment: `printf("%d", A);` is wrong. Maybe you wanted `printf("%d", A->d);` or perhaps `printf("%p", (void*)A);`

Answer (score 1):

> when we did A = temp, this is not clear, what did we assigned exactly?

`temp` contains the the address of the node allocated by `malloc`.

You assigned this to `A`. (`A = temp;`)

So `A` contains the the address of the node allocated by `malloc`.

---

> Now can I get from A to the next node

What next node? You only ever created one node.

---

> I was expecting A->next to store the address of temp, no?

At no point do you get the address of `temp`. And there's no point in doing that. So I think you mean the address of the node (the address *in* `temp`). But why wou ld that be in `A->next`? You never assign `temp` to `A->next`. You assign `NULL` to `A->next` (`temp->next = NULL;`).

> Please if you can explain in the simplest terms the basic abstract inner workings?

- `temp` holds the address of the node you allocated.
- You assign this to `A`, so it holds the same address.
- `*temp` and `*A` is the node you allocated.
- `(*temp).data` aka `temp->data` is its `data` field (currently containing `2`).
- Since `A` has the same value as `temp`, `(*A).data` aka `A->data` can also be used to access its `data` field.
- `(*temp).next` aka `temp->next` is the address of the next node (currently `NULL`).
- Since `A` has the same value as `temp`, `(*A).next` aka `A->next` can also be used to access its `next` field.

```
Node *temp               Node anon
@ 0x1000                 @ 0x2000
+------------+           +------------+
| 0x2000  ---------+---->| data:    2 |
+------------+     |     | next: NULL |
                   |     +------------+
Node *A            |
@ 0x1004           |
+------------+     |
| 0x2000  ---------+
+------------+
```

(The addresses are completely made up, of course.)

---

> Is the following code correct?

No. You have:

```c
Node* A = NULL;
...
A->next = temp;
```

`A` is `NULL`. It doesn't point to a node. So attempting to set the `next` field of the node to which `A` points makes no sense. This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I get what you wrote, the issue I am having is that I don't get why I would do `A = temp` if I want a chain linked list where A points to temp, let s say we want to have a linked list with one element, with the head being `A`. See my updated post.

Comment: Answered your additional question in my answer.